# htaccess rewrite rule for url parts

Tags: regex, .htaccess

My url looks lik:

```
http://example/en/account/register
```

I want to catch with regexp this url

```
RewriteRule ^(\w{2}+)/(^account)$
```

In this rule I want have all url that contain `http://example/en/account/`

I can't found where is problem in my regexp, because this regexp is not correct for that url ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w{2})/(account)/?$ your-handler [L]
```

2 points about your regex:

1. To catch 2 letter language use `\w{2}` not `\w{2}+`
2. You cannot use anchor `^` in the middle of your regex as it means start of input.